# How to use pyramid @view_defaults to specify multiple routes for same view

Tags: decorator, pyramid

I'm finding I can use multiple @view_config decorators to cause a view to handle more than one route, like this:

```
@view_config(route_name = "user_create")
@view_config(route_name = "user_edit")
def handle_it(request):
    pass
```

But when I try to achieve the same thing with the class decorator,  @view_defaults, it doesn't work:

```
@view_defaults(route_name = "user_create")
@view_defaults(route_name = "user_edit")
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
    def handle_it(self):
        pass
```

What happens in this last case is the first route mentioned (user_create) is honored by pyramid, but request for the user_edit route produces a 404 error.

Shouldn't I be able to use @view_defaults this way?
Michael

Answer (score 1):

`view_defaults` are used as an input to each `view_config` call. They are not a replacement. The only thing routing cares about is the actual views registered, which is done with `view_config` or `config.add_view`. `view_defaults` does not register views.